# Value count of complex numbers with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

why does the following

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,2+1j,4,5+1j])

c = df[0].value_counts()
```

result in

```
(2+0j)  2
(5+0j)  1
(4+0j)  1
(1+0j)  1
```

rather than

```
(2+0j)  1
(2+1j)  1
(5+1j)  1
(4+0j)  1
(1+0j)  1
```

Are the imaginary parts of complex numbers ignored?

Answer (score 2):

```
    values = _ensure_object(values)
    mask = isnull(values)
    keys, counts = htable.value_count_object(values, mask)
    if not dropna and mask.any():
        keys = np.insert(keys, 0, np.NaN)
        counts = np.insert(counts, 0, mask.sum())
```

is the code in pandas.core.algorithms that does your work https://tedboy.github.io/pandas/_modules/pandas/core/algorithms.html. The htable only looks at the real component.  I suggest that you put in a request to update this to deal with this case...